# can't get access token with code

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, facebook-access-token

I'm using javascript sdk for user login

```
FB.init({appId: applicationId, status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true});
FB.login(callbackFunction, {scope:permissions});
```

i get valid access token in authResponse, and also a signed cookie is set, which decoded has code.

according to documentation access token could be retrieved with

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&code=THE_CODE_FROM_ABOVE

when i try this with the code i receive error **Error validating verification code. 100**

as redirect_uri i've tried uri that is set as App Domain and siteURL. these give that error. with other uri i get **Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration. 191**

Am i here mixing client-side flow and server-side flow in bad way or should i use some redirect_uri parameter when using `FB.init` or `FB.login` and use that exact uri when getting access token by code?

Comment: Are you sure your callbackFunction is decoding the key correctly?  Dont post it, but it should look something like 111111_111111111111?  Does your access_token and client_id match?  Aka are you sure you are passing the correct access_token to request the key?

Answer (score 0):

`FB.login(callbackFunction, {scope:permissions});`
the callback function is sent an object

```
       authResponse: {          /* Information about the current session */
          userID: ""          /* String representing the current user's ID */
          signedRequest: "",  /* String with the current signedRequest */
          expiresIn: "",      /* UNIX time when the session expires */
          accessToken: "",    /* Access token of the user */
       }
```

In here is the user access token that does not need to be converted by calling another URL.  It's ready to go for about an hour, then you'll need to get a new one.